# Joining multiple tables on a calendar table with minute resolution

Tags: mysql, performance, join, calendar

A brief overview of the scenario:

We have a data logging system on a ship where various sensors are reading in real-time data and storing that data in a MySQL database.

Each sensor has a table, where the instantaneous sensor values are time-stamped and stored in the database.

The requirement now is to merge data for all sensors into a single table with values averaged per minute between two date-time values.

**Here is what I've done so far:**

*1. Created a stored procedure to create a calendar table.*
The calendar procedure creates a table with date-time stamps between two specified date-time values.
For the cruise report I'm working on the calendar table looks like this:

```
cal
-------------------+
dt            
-------------------+
2012-07-09 00:00:00
2012-07-09 00:01:00
2012-07-09 00:02:00

... etc

2012-07-29 23:57:00
2012-07-29 23:58:00
2012-07-29 23:59:00
```

30241 records in total, fetched in 0.016 seconds so no problem there.

*2. Created temporary tables for sensor values averaged on the minute.*

Example of an averaged sensor table:

```
tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave
-------------------+------------------
tmstamp            | average_heading
-------------------+------------------
2012-07-09 00:00:00, 135.633333333333
2012-07-09 00:01:00, 135.633333333333
2012-07-09 00:02:00, 136.1
2012-07-09 00:03:00, 135.433333333333
etc...

29546 records fetched in 0.047 secs
```

and another sensor table:

```
tbl_par_sensor_1min_ave
-------------------+------------------
tmstamp            | average_par
-------------------+------------------
2012-07-09 00:00:00, 16.269949
2012-07-09 00:01:00, 16.270832
2012-07-09 00:02:00, 16.2637752
2012-07-09 00:03:00, 16.2678025
2012-07-09 00:04:00, 16.269324
2012-07-09 00:05:00, 16.2721382
etc...

29543 records fetched in 0.047 secs
```

*3. Now joining the temporary tables to the calendar table is where the wheels come off.*

To join a single table to the calendar table, I do this:

```
 SELECT cal.dt, tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave.average_heading
    FROM cal

    LEFT JOIN tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave
    ON cal.dt = tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave.tmstamp
```

Explain for above query:

```
+----+---------------+-----------------------+--------+---------------+-------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| Id |  Select_Type  |  Table                |  Type  | Possible_Keys | Key   | Key_Len | Ref  | Rows  | Extra       |
+----+---------------+-----------------------+--------+---------------+-------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| 1  |  SIMPLE       | cal                   |  index | NULL          | dt    | 9       | NULL | 30243 | Using index |
| 1  |  SIMPLE       | tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave |  ALL   | date_index    | NULL  | NULL    | NULL | 29546 |             |
+----+---------------+-----------------------+--------+---------------+-------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
```

For really small datasets, this works fine, but for the example above, it just hangs.
I've tried to add indexes to all the tables, same result.

**Edit>**  I let this run overnight for the full dataset.

The result:

Fetched 30243 records.

Duration: 23.697 sec, **fetched in 3000.352 sec**

Next step would be to join more than two tables against the calendar table like this:

```
 SELECT cal.dt, tbl_par_sensor_1min_ave.average_par, tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave.average_heading
    FROM tbl_par_sensor_1min_ave

    LEFT JOIN cal
    ON cal.dt = tbl_par_sensor_1min_ave.tmstamp

    LEFT JOIN tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave
    ON cal.dt = tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave.tmstamp
```

Not surprisingly, this also hangs.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

As requested in the comments below, here are the table schemas:

```
show columns from cal;
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| dt    | datetime | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


show columns from  tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave;
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| tmstamp         | varchar(24) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| average_heading | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


show columns from tbl_par_sensor_1min_ave;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| tmstamp     | varchar(24) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| average_par | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Solved:**

After implementing setsuna's changes:

Single outer join:

```
SELECT cal.dt, tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave.average_heading
FROM cal
LEFT JOIN tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave
ON cal.dt = tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave.tmstamp  

Fetched 30243 records 
Duration: 0.015 sec
Fetched in: 0.172 sec
```

Double outer join:

```
SELECT cal.dt, tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave.average_heading, tbl_par_sensor_1min_ave.average_par
FROM cal
LEFT JOIN tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave
ON cal.dt = tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave.tmstamp  
LEFT JOIN tbl_par_sensor_1min_ave
ON cal.dt = tbl_par_sensor_1min_ave.tmstamp  

Fetched 29543 records
Duration: 0.000s
Fetched in: 0.281 sec
```

Comment: Can you show your table schema information?

Comment: Run an explain on both your single left join and multiple left join queries and post that in your question please. Also, what specific indexes did you try?

Comment: Suggestion for a workaround: Store the averages in a separate table and insert in it only calendar entries which have not yet any averages computed.

Comment: Thank you for the comments so far. I've added the table schemas as asked.  Also, I let the first join query run overnight, and posted the result, took almost an hour!  I will run an explain as well, this will take a similar amount of time I would imagine.  Alex, I'm not sure I follow your logic, could you elaborate a bit?  Thanks again for all the input.

Comment: Change column cal.dt to NOT NULL as well as both the tmstamp to TIMESTAMP or DATETIME and NOT NULL. A JOIN with ~30,000 records and properly indexed JOIN condition fields should be running quite fast.

Comment: I added the explain for the first join query.

Comment: Why would you use a sensor per table? Why not add a sensor table and put the key in a sensor_data table? That way you can easy aggregate over the data.

Comment: Thanks @setsuna , if you want to post the answer I can delete mine and mark you up.  Rogier:  the example I gave above is a simplified view of the system as a whole.  Some sensors give multiple values, some sensors like GPS are not averaged etc.  I'm sure it can be optimised greatly, and we will continue to do so incrementally, sensors do not fit nicely into a simple parent-child relation.  Thanks for your input, I have  much to learn.  My first experience on stackoverflow has been a very pleasant one, thanks all.

Comment: @Knapie I converted to an answer with a note for others to check your answer. Don't delete anything, just mark my answer as accepted. Glad it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change column *cal.dt* to **NOT NULL** as well as both the *tmstamp* to **TIMESTAMP** or **DATETIME** and **NOT NULL**. A JOIN with ~30,000 records and properly indexed JOIN condition fields should be running quite fast.

**Note:** @Knapie already gave the results of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Thank you to setsuna (see comments)

> Change column cal.dt to NOT NULL as well as both the tmstamp to
>   TIMESTAMP or DATETIME and NOT NULL. A JOIN with ~30,000 records and
>   properly indexed JOIN condition fields should be running quite fast.

After implementing setsuna's changes:

Single outer join:

```
SELECT cal.dt, tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave.average_heading
FROM cal
LEFT JOIN tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave
ON cal.dt = tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave.tmstamp 

Fetched 30243 records 
Duration: 0.015 sec
Fetched in: 0.172 sec
```

Double outer join:

```
SELECT cal.dt, tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave.average_heading, tbl_par_sensor_1min_ave.average_par
FROM cal
LEFT JOIN tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave
ON cal.dt = tbl_gyro_hdt_1min_ave.tmstamp  
LEFT JOIN tbl_par_sensor_1min_ave
ON cal.dt = tbl_par_sensor_1min_ave.tmstamp  

Fetched 29543 records
Duration: 0.000s
Fetched in: 0.281 sec
```